# Error with _DataLoaderIter in torch.utils.data.dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run a code which needs to import `_DataLoaderIter` from `torch.utils.data.dataloader`. By checking the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html) for dataloader class, that method exist. However, I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 4, in
>
> import data
>
> File "D:\Hyperspectral Data\RCAN\RCAN_TrainCode\code\data\__init__.py", line 3, in module
>
> from dataloader import MSDataLoader
>
> File "D:\Hyperspectral Data\RCAN\RCAN_TrainCode\code\dataloader.py", line 14, in module
>
> from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _DataLoaderIter
>
> ImportError: cannot import name '_DataLoaderIter'

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which version of PyTorch are you using? For me, on 1.0.0, `from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _DataLoaderIter` works fine. I noticed that in your traceback you have `code\data__init__.py`. Notice the lack of `\` between `data` and `__init__.py` - perhaps this has something to do with the error?

Comment: @Jatentaki I am using pytorch version 0.3.1 on a Windows 10 OS. I suspect that problem is with pytorch for Windows. Are you using Windows? The lack of '\' in the traceback was just mistyped. I editted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment answers the question: the `_DataLoaderIter` is there in `1.0.0` (for which you are linking documentation) but not in `0.3.1`, as you can check [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html#DataLoader) - its name has no preceding `_`.

This is a textbook example why it is a bad idea to access other packages' private classes/functions (customarily prefixed with an underscore) - you have zero guarantees on the stability of their implementation and behavior. If you need their code, it's usually better to copy-paste the code to your own file, because there it is at least guaranteed to not change between updates and bug fixes to `torch`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new virtual environment and install Torch0.4.0 for this specific repo. I had the same problem and reinstalling Torch v0.4.0 did the trick for me